# how to show the current day in week view of telerik scheduler

Tags: telerik

i wish to show the current day highlighted in week view... how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Telerik website](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/scheduler/radschedular-monthview-s-current-day.aspx) (I no longer have their stuff loaded to test this out myself), you should be able to set the current day by doing something like:

```
RadSchedulerCommands.SetWeekViewMode.Execute(Nothing, SchedulerTest) 
SchedulerTest.SelectedTimeSlot = New TimeSlot(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)) 
RadSchedulerCommands.SetMonthViewMode.Execute(Nothing, SchedulerTest)
```

where SchedulerTest is the name of your scheduler control.